# Is it possible to alter multiple columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

for example if I have the following:

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN col_a TYPE double precision USING ( NULLIF( col_a, '') ::double precision);
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN col_b TYPE double precision USING ( NULLIF( col_b, '') ::double precision);
```

I was wondering whether I could reduce the code, to have this in one line.

In addition, I was wondering whether because this is on two lines, will it perform slower in Postgres than a rewritten SQL query in one line?

Comment: Changed title to better describe what you are asking. The answer is yes. See [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) : "All the forms of ALTER TABLE that act on a single table, except RENAME, SET SCHEMA, ATTACH PARTITION, and DETACH PARTITION can be combined into a list of multiple alterations to be applied together. For example, it is possible to add several columns and/or alter the type of several columns in a single command. This is particularly useful with large tables, since only one pass over the table need be made."

Comment: Yes, however, the NULLIF part, applies to the respective column. I was wondering how I can map this over the multiple columns.

Comment: You can't `USING` is applied to a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. To spell it out:

```
ALTER TABLE test
   ALTER col_a TYPE double precision USING (NULLIF(col_a, '')::double precision),
   ALTER col_b TYPE double precision USING (NULLIF(col_b, '')::double precision);
```